# Import PFX Certificate via PowerShell with full certificate chain

Tags: windows, powershell, ssl-certificate

It's SSL certificate replacement time, and while I could, for my Windows servers, do this the tedious way (Certificates mmc, import manually), I'm looking for something I can automate via some PowerShell scripting.

I know about [Import-PfxCertificate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/import-pfxcertificate?view=win10-ps), and to import a .pfx I'd do something like:

```
$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "PrivateKeyPasswordGoesHere" -AsPlainText -Force
Import-PfxCertificate -Password $pwd -FilePath "\\path\to\pfxfile\pfxfile.pfx" -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My -Exportable # optional if i want the private key to be exportable
```

This is all well and good, but unlike the manual tedious way it only brings in the entity certificate itself; it doesn't bring in any other certificates in the full chain (root, intermediates, etc).

It *looks as if* I may be able to do something with [Get-PfxData](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/get-pfxdata?view=win10-ps), which "*extracts the content of a Personal Information Exchange (PFX) file into a structure that contains the end entity certificate, any intermediate and root certificates*", but [Import-Certificate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/import-certificate?view=win10-ps) has a mandatory FilePath parameter, so I can't pipe the output of Get-PfxData to it.

**I've used Get-PfxData to verify that the PFX does indeed contain the full chain**.

I've also tried the following approach:

- Import manually to the Certificates mmc.
- Use Export-PfxCertificate to export the full chain (which one must assume does so in a format that's consumable by Import-PfxCertificate).
- Use Import-PfxCertificate to import the exported certificate.

But again, Import-PfxCertificate does not bring in the full chain.

Any other options for cracking this nut?

Comment: Your PFX must include these certificates first. Are chain certificates are included in PFX?

Comment: @Crypt32 - the PFX does include them, I've verified this with Get-PfxData which can see them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this manually, using the Certificates mmc.

Ultimately there does not appear to be sufficient assurance that the PowerShell method can reproduce the same behaviour as the mmc, and for business-critical applications the assurance from using the mmc was important enough to take the hit in time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

If the full certificates chain is part of the PFX file, `Import-PfxCertificate` will import all related certificates as well and place them into the appropriate folder.

There is nothing else you need to do.

Comment: The PFX does include them, I've verified this with Get-PfxData which can see them.

Comment: I just tested this with a brand new Server 2019 and a Lets Encrypt PFX file and it imports all three certificates. Not sure why that doesn't work for you.

Comment: If you double click the certificate in the MMC, and open the `Certification Path` tab, what does it show?

Answer (score 0):

I tested this as well and the `Import-PfxCertificate` does import the chain, but if the chain certs already exist (which was my case) they don't show up in personal certificates. I was able to bind my pfx to my website and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't include your output for `Get-PfxData`, I'm not sure if my solution applies to your issue. But here is mine:

```
PS> Get-PfxData -FilePath "\\path\to\cert.p12" -Password $pwd | Format-List

OtherCertificates     : {[Subject]
                          CN=mkcert MSEDGEWIN10\IEUser@MSEDGEWIN10 (IEUser), OU=MSEDGEWIN10\IEUser@MSEDGEWIN10 (IEUser), O=mkcert development CA
                         ...
                        }
EndEntityCertificates : {[Subject]
                          CN=localhost, OU=MSEDGEWIN10\IEUser@MSEDGEWIN10 (IEUser), O=mkcert development certificate
                         ...
                        }
```

Notably, there are two arrays of certificates as returned by `Get-PfxData`: `OtherCertificates` and `EndEntityCertificates`

If I tried to import the certificates directly with `Import-PfxCertificate Cert:\CurrentUser\Root -FilePath "\\path\to\cert.p12" -Password $pwd`, only the certificate in `EndEntityCertificate` would end up in the desired `Cert:\CurrentUser\Root`. The certificate in `OtherCertificates` would instead end up in `Cert:\CurrentUser\CA` and wouldn't be trusted

---

To solve this problem, I ended up having to directly call .NET functions (which PowerShell provides convenient access to), and edit the store explicitly:

```
$store = Get-Item Cert:\CurrentUser\Root
$store.Open([Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags]::ReadWrite)
$cert = Get-PfxData -FilePath "\\path\to\cert.p12" -Password $pwd
$store.AddRange([Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection]::new($cert.EndEntityCertificates + $cert.OtherCertificates))
```

How does this work?
`Get-Item` on a certificate store returns a [`X509Store`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509store) object, which has the [`AddRange()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509store.addrange) method that lets you merge a [`X509Certificate2Collection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2collection) object (a wrapper over multiple [`X509Certificate2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2)s) into the store.
Since the `OtherCertificates` and `EndEntityCertificates` properties of what `Get-PfxData` returns are arrays of `X509Certificate2`s, they can be simply concatenated together and converted into a `X509Certificate2Collection` to be merged into the store